# Date is not displayed in TableView

Tags: java, sql-server, javafx

I have 6 column in sql server table 5 of them are displayed in TableView, 6 is in Date format which is not shown there is no error showing anything.

```
public class PTable {
    String P_total,P_sold,P_correct,P_remaining,P_faulty;
    LocalDate P_addedDate;
    public PTable(String P_total,String P_sold,String P_correct,String P_remaining,String P_faulty,LocalDate P_addedDate){
        this.P_total=P_total;
        this.P_sold = P_sold;
        this.P_correct=P_correct;
        this.P_remaining=P_remaining;
        this.P_faulty=P_faulty;
        this.P_addedDate=P_addedDate;
    }
    public String getP_total(){
        return P_total;
    }
    public void setP_total(String P_total){
        this.P_total=P_total;
    }
    public String getP_sold(){
        return P_sold;
    }
    public void setP_sold(String P_sold){
        this.P_sold=P_sold;
    }
    public String getP_correct(){
        return P_correct;
    }
    public void setP_correct(String P_correct){
        this.P_correct=P_correct;
    }
    public String getP_remaining(){
        return P_remaining;
    }
    public void setP_remaining(String P_remaining){
        this.P_remaining=P_remaining;
    }
    public String getP_faulty(){
        return P_faulty;
    }
    public void setP_faulty(String P_faulty){
        this.P_faulty=P_faulty;
    }
    public LocalDate getP_addedDate(){
        return P_addedDate;
    }
    public void setP_addedDate(LocalDate P_addedDate){
        this.P_addedDate=P_addedDate;
    }
}
```

My Controller Class::

```
ObservableList<PTable> ob = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("select * from Products");
    while(rs.next()){
        ob.add(new PTable(rs.getString("P_total"),rs.getString("P_sold"),rs.getString("P_correct"),rs.getString("P_remaining"),rs.getString("P_faulty"),rs.getDate("P_addedDate").toLocalDate()));
    }
    TProduct_cln.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PTable , String>("P_total"));
    SProduct_cln.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PTable , String>("P_sold"));
    CProduct_col.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PTable , String>("P_correct"));
    RProduct_cln.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PTable , String>("P_remaining"));
    FProduct_cln.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PTable , String>("P_faulty"));
    date_cln.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PTable , LocalDate>("P_addedDate"));
    tbl_product.setItems(ob);
```

Please do help me on this. I have been trying for 2 days and still got no solution.
Thanks

Comment: I don’t know whether it solves your issue, but since JDBC 4.2 you should use `rs.getObject("P_addedDate", LocalDate.class)`.

Comment: Isolate the problem. Is the issue that you’re not getting the value from the result set, or is the problem that the tableview isn’t displaying it?

Comment: [mcve] please .. and stick to java naming conventions!

Comment: Thank you for your response but the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the `CellFactory` in your code. If thats the case try this:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
date_cln.setCellFactory(column -> new TableCell<PTable, LocalDate>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(LocalDate date, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(date, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText("");
        } else {
            setText(formatter.format(date));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: true, but the OP should see _something_ even without a formatting cell, right ;)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is solved. I changed 2 things in my code
First change the LocalDate to String.
Then rs.getDate("P_addedDate").toLocalDate() change it to rs.getDate("P_addedDate").toString();
it solved my issue, thought it might help somebody else.

Comment: that's not a solution, it only smears over a problem which will bite again .. it's wrong to have all data as string, doing something reasonable in representing the any data type is the task of the cell